# MySQL: Convert column into rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a zillion of colums that I need to convert into rows.

I have 3 main categories (CAT, ODB & GPA)
Each category has a month (From Jan, to Dec) and each category has a year)
Here is a sample of the structure:

> CATJAN2002 | CATFEB2002...| CATDEC2002...| ODBJAN2003...| GPAMAR2013

In vba I can create a simple loop, to export this data into another table:

`New_Table` fields:
`ID, TYPE, YEAR, MONTH, VALUE`
. Can YOU PLEASE help me find a way to automatically go thought the table's columns and start inputing the data into the new table? Can this be done in MySQL alone?

I forgot to menton that the combination of the first columns (STORE, ITEM  & CUSTOMER ) is the ID (Or primary key) [`SELECT CONCAT(STORE, ITEM, CUSTOMER) AS ID`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table

Comment: How many rows in your original table? within an order of magnitude.

Comment: @MarcAudet I am guessing about 400. If there are 3 categories for 12 months from 2002 - 2013

Comment: Write a script and map columns from the old table to the new schema.  This is not that hard to do but it is hard to be elegant.

Comment: if its only 400 rows, there's not much need to be elegant, particularly if it's a one-off task.

Comment: @MarcAudet I have 72 columns that I need them to convert into rows as `ID, type` (The first three characters of the column), `year` (The last characters) and `month` where I need to convert the month into a number

Comment: So, the original table has one row with 72 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use a query like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(STORE, ITEM, CUSTOMER) ID,
       'CAT' TYPE, 2002 YEAR, 'JAN' MONTH, CATJAN2002 VALUE
FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(STORE, ITEM, CUSTOMER) ID,
       'CAT' TYPE, 2002 YEAR, 'FEB' MONTH, CATFEB2002 VALUE
FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
...
```

And you can make it using a dynamic query, like this:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT CONCAT(STORE, ITEM, CUSTOMER) ID,',
    '\'',
    LEFT(column_name, 3),
    '\' TYPE,',
    RIGHT(column_name, 4),
    ' YEAR, \'',
    SUBSTR(column_name, 4, 3),
    '\' MONTH,',
    column_name,
    ' VALUE FROM yourtable')
  SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
where
  table_name = 'yourtable'
  AND (column_name LIKE 'CAT%' OR column_name LIKE 'ODB%' OR column_name LIKE 'GPA%')
INTO @sql;

prepare stm from @sql;
execute stm;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff6223/1).

Comment: I forgot to menton that the combination of the first columns (STORE, ITEM  & CUSTOMER ) is the ID (Or primary key) [`SELECT CONCAT(STORE, ITEM, CUSTOMER) AS ID`