# How to change columnHeaders to fieldValues?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me take straight away a concrete example. I have one table that look like this:

```
id,john,jack,jimy
 1,22,NULL,NULL
 2,NULL,55,66
```

I would like to know if it is possible with an sql to change that table to the following table:

```
id,person,value
 1,john,22
 2,jack,55
 3,jimy,66
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table

Comment: Your question doesn't match your requirement. Are you talking about converting column <-> row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portable SQL:

```
select 1 as id, 'john' as person, max(john) as value from yourtable
union all
select 2 as id, 'jack' as person, max(jack) as value from yourtable
union all
select 3 as id, 'jimy' as person, max(jimy) as value from yourtable
```

Replace `max` with an aggregate of your choice in case there are multiple non-NULL values in any column.

Comment: The original table in question isn't right. It should have 3 rows, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use UNPIVOT:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), VALUE, PERSON
from Table1
unpivot (value for person in (john,jack,jimy)) A
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29118/10/0)

**UPDATE**

When I provided this solution, there was no tags to guide me. I don't think this solution will work in MySQL, then you could try:

```
 select 1, 'John' Person, max(John) Value from Table1 UNION
 select 2, 'Jack' Person, max(Jack) Value from Table1 UNION
 select 3, 'Jimy' Person, max(Jimy) Value from Table1
```

As showed in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/151c9/3/0)

Comment: ty that is a good hint but do you think it will work with mySQL?

Comment: The output provided by your SQL Server suggestion doesn't exactly match the OP's expected output, does it? Please consider removing it.

Comment: @AndriyM You mean because the ID was not distinct for each person? The new ID keep no relation with the old one, right? IF so, I've made adjustments to my query to return sequential IDs for each person.