# Turn Columns into Rows SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a set of table of data that looks like this:

```
[id],[testid],[date],[type],[score1],[score2],[score3],[score4]
```

I need it to look like this

```
[id],[testid][date],[type],[score],[scorecode] (score1)
[id],[testid][date],[type],[score],[scorecode] (score2)
[id],[testid][date],[type],[score],[scorecode] (score3)
[id],[testid][date],[type],[score],[scorecode] (score4)
```

The scorecode is dependent on which score(1-4), so the score1 row would need a scorecode of ACTMATH, score2 would need a different scorecode.

When I orginally built this, I used UNION ALL.  However, I just want to make sure there's not a more efficient way of completing this.

Answer (score 1):

You should break out the Scores into their own `table`

Which it has a ScoreCode and Score and a link back to the Id of the Test

And then you would do a SQL `Join` query and easily get your results in that format.

Tests
    [testid],[date],[type]
Scores
    [ScoreId],[testid],[score],[scorecode]

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tests T
JOIN Scores S
ON T.Testid = S.TestId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other way than using `UNION`.

You can check these other question: [Mysql Convert Column to row (Pivot table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table)