# phpmyadmin manipulating data from another query result

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have MySQL table looking like this :

```
bank_code | jan | feb | mar | apr | mei |
-----------------------------------------
bca       | 500 | 300 | 200 | 400 | 350 |
bii       | 100 | 230 | 0   | 250 | 0   |
bni       | 340 | 235 | 800 | 870 | 780 |
```

Is it possible to run a MySQL query to get output like this:

```
month | bca | bii | bni |
-------------------------
jan   | 500 | 100 | 340 |
feb   | 300 | 230 | 235 |
mar   | 200 | 0   | 800 |
apr   | 400 | 250 | 870 |
mei   | 350 | 0   | 780 |
```

The bank_code is dynamic data, count of bank_code is not always 3.

I have tried many links that looks similar (http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html), but I still failed. As I searching, this would be possible using dynamic pivot table by concat or group concat, but I'm newbie for this and I don't understand how to do it. Anyone can help ? Thanks before..

Comment: That's more of "transposing" than "pivoting".

Comment: The code in SQL would be painful and ugly.  Use PHP or some other real programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sub query in the from clause will let you work with the dinamic result:
    SELECT *
    from (
        SELECT *.back_code_data
    ) as dinamic
    ...

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I don't understand what you mean.. can you give me an example ?

Comment: Can you give me the two sqls you want tu run?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4926c/1 is the example I made by SQL Fiddle.. So far, I just made single rows..

Comment: This link explian more in deep what you want to implement in MySQL. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table