# Transpose result from query mysql

Tags: mysql

I think this is silly question. Is t possible transpose the result from query on mysql?

I have query like this :

```
SELECT SUM(a.BALANCE) AS STORAGE,
 (SELECT SUM(LIFT_ON) FROM tb_fin_repo b WHERE LPAD(MONTH( b.DATE_OUT), 2, 0) = 05) AS REPO,
 (SELECT SUM(CLEANING) FROM tb_fin_cleaning c WHERE LPAD(MONTH(c.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05) AS CLEANING,
 (SELECT SUM(ONE_BAR) FROM tb_fin_one_bar d WHERE LPAD(MONTH(d.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05) AS ONE_BAR,
 (SELECT SUM(YEARS2) FROM tb_fin_test_periodic e WHERE LPAD(MONTH(e.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05) AS YEARS2,
 (SELECT SUM(YEARS5) FROM tb_fin_test_periodic f WHERE LPAD(MONTH(f.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05) AS YEARS5,
 (SELECT SUM(REPAIR) FROM tb_fin_repair g WHERE LPAD(MONTH(g.OUT_DATE),2,0)) AS REPAIR

 FROM tb_fin_storage a
 WHERE LPAD(MONTH( a.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05
```

The result is :

```
+---------+--------+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| STORAGE | REPO   | CLEANING | ONE_BAR | YEARS2 | YEARS5 | REPAIR  |
+---------+--------+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| 2210.40 | 108.00 |  9490.00 | 1512.00 | 250.00 | 540.00 | 7651.95 |
+---------+--------+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need like this :

```
+-------------+---------+
| DESCRIPTION |  VALUE  |
+-------------+---------+
| STORAGE     | 2210.40 |
| REPO        | 108.00  |
| CLEANING    | 9490.00 |
| ONE_BAR     | 1512.00 |
| YEARS2      | 250.00  |
| YEARS5      | 540.00  |
| REPAIR      | 7651.95 |
+-------------+---------+
```

Is it possible, for the help is so appreciated

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT 'STORAGE' as description, SUM(a.BALANCE) AS STORAGE  FROM tb_fin_storage a
WHERE LPAD(MONTH( a.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'REPO',SUM(LIFT_ON) FROM tb_fin_repo b
WHERE LPAD(MONTH( b.DATE_OUT), 2, 0) = 05
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLEANING' , SUM(CLEANING) FROM tb_fin_cleaning c
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(c.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05) 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ONE_BAR',SUM(ONE_BAR) FROM tb_fin_one_bar d
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(d.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05) 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'YEARS2' , SUM(YEARS2) FROM tb_fin_test_periodic e
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(e.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05
UNION ALL
SELECT 'YEARS5' , SUM(YEARS5) FROM tb_fin_test_periodic f
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(f.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05
UNION ALL
SELECT 'REPAIR' , SUM(REPAIR) FROM tb_fin_repair g 
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(g.OUT_DATE),2,0)
```

Comment: How about get the total of value, commonly I use in PHP, but, is it possible directly from mysql ?

Comment: You want only the total value, or this query + total value ? @FadlyDzil

Answer (score 1):

This is not very best query I ever seen, but just to give you an idea of what you are asking for.

You can use `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'STORAGE' as DESCRIPTION,SUM(a.BALANCE) as Value
FROM tb_fin_storage a
WHERE LPAD(MONTH( a.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05
UNION
SELECT 'REPO',SUM(LIFT_ON) 
FROM tb_fin_repo b 
WHERE LPAD(MONTH( b.DATE_OUT), 2, 0) = 05
UNION
SELECT 'CLEANING',SUM(CLEANING) 
FROM tb_fin_cleaning c 
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(c.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05
UNION
SELECT 'ONE_BAR',SUM(ONE_BAR) 
FROM tb_fin_one_bar d 
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(d.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05
UNION
SELECT 'YEARS2',SUM(YEARS2) 
FROM tb_fin_test_periodic e 
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(e.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05
UNION
SELECT 'YEARS5',SUM(YEARS5) 
FROM tb_fin_test_periodic f 
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(f.OUT_DATE), 2, 0) = 05
UNION
SELECT 'REPAIR', SUM(REPAIR) 
FROM tb_fin_repair g 
WHERE LPAD(MONTH(g.OUT_DATE),2,0)
```

Didn't you forget `= 05` at the `tb_fin_repair WHERE` ?

Comment: `UNION ALL` should be faster

Comment: @sagi since every subquery return just 1 row, I don't think that there will be any visible difference. But technically you are right `UNION ALL` could be faster.

Comment: You know what? I take that back, didn't even look at the query. You are right, the difference won't be visible:)

Comment: How about get the total of value, commonly I use in PHP, but, is it possible directly from mysql ?