# Order column values from the selected row

Tags: mysql

I've a table where I've 4 columns int type.

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
   3     2     3     4
   2     2     4     3
```

And I'm trying to select those values in ordered form like:

```
colx  colx  colx  colx
   2     3     3     4
```

Column names does not matter in result, also having result as one col is welcomed (if concatenated in some fashion):

```
colx
2.3.3.4
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want information from ascending order or descending order? is that is your question?

Comment: It's clear instead, cuz I showed what I wanted, but not matter ascending or descending any case is welcomed

Comment: You want to make sorting based on columns and not rows right? Afaik this is not something SQL deals with but you can pivot them check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table

Comment: @Fma yes that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Is this for selecting one row or multiple rows at a time

Comment: @Fma I don't want piloting just want to order values in rows

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's one row level but will need for multiple rows for sure

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili I don't think you can do otherwise because SQL deals with rows and designed to work like that. It is probably better to to it manually in another language or use a pivot table and return its result as a new row.

Comment: Even if you did do this, how would the data returned be of any use as you no longer know what column is in what order. Surely the data becomes meaningless

Comment: What is the database type. This matters because the approach to follow and syntax will differ by dbms. If tsql you could unpivot, sort those rows, then concatenate.

Comment: Any primary key column for the table?

Comment: Sorry i now see the mysql tag. Apologies. ... Yep. Just saw it.

Comment: I want to select unique number sets. I mean 3 2 1 3 is same as 2 3 3 1

Comment: and want to identify that

Comment: Normalise your schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single row it could be done with the current structure however if you have multiple rows you need a primary or any unique key.

Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | id   |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    3 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    1 |
|    4 |    7 |    1 |    3 |    2 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Now the query would be as

```
select 
id,
group_concat(x.col order by x.col separator '.') as colx
from ( 
  select id,col1 as col from test 
  union all 
  select id,col2 as col from test 
  union all 
  select id,col3 as col from test 
  union all 
  select id,col4 as col from test
)x group by id
```

The result will look like

```
+------+---------+
| id   | colx    |
+------+---------+
|    1 | 2.3.3.4 |
|    2 | 1.3.4.7 |
+------+---------+
```