# MySQL - Convert Column to Rows using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pivot, unpivot

I know we have to pivot and unpivot a table to convert column to rows in mysql as given in the link below : 
[link to the code for converting columns to rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table)

But can anyone tell me how to create a stored procedure for this. I have 15,000 rows and many columns which need to be looped through for pivoting. If anyone can help me on how to create a dynamic stored procedure for the above given link it would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be in MySQL, or can it be written in, for example, python?

Comment: I need the pivoted table dynamic stored procedure in MySQL. Is it possible to do in MySQL? I have been trying to figure it out but I am not able to run the procedure without errors.