# How to pivot columns to rows in MySQL for N number of columns without using Union all

Tags: mysql

I already went through the details in the link ([Mysql Convert Column to row (Pivot table )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table)). As the number of Columns is high and using union all on all of them would be time taking. I decided to use the last resolution in the given link. I was able to run the query the results were:

[image]

[image]

The issue is the acct getting included as data and also I want to create a table from the result . So Can these entries be excluded and how can I create a table from the results? (new to SQL)

```
The Code:

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 92160;
SET @target_schema='rd';
SET @target_table='pbc_gl';
SET @target_where='`acct`';



SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(qry SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
    INTO @sql
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONCAT('SELECT `acct`,', QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME), ' AS `Business_Unit`,`', COLUMN_NAME, '` AS `value` FROM `', @target_table, '` WHERE ', @target_where) qry
    FROM (
        SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
        FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`=@target_schema 
            AND `TABLE_NAME`=@target_table
    ) AS `A`
) AS `B` ;

PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

Comment: Add `AND COLUMN_NAME != 'acct'` to the query.

Comment: Thank you. Could you let me know who to create a table from this ? new to SQL

Comment: You can prepend `CREATE TABLE new_tbl_name ` to your SELECT statement.

Comment: SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(qry SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
    INTO @sql
FROM (CREATE TABLE new_tbl_name
          SELECT
        CONCAT('SELECT `acct`,', QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME), ' AS `Business_Unit`,`', COLUMN_NAME, '` AS `value` FROM `', @target_table, '` WHERE ', @target_where) qry
    FROM (
        SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
        FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`=@target_schema 
            AND `TABLE_NAME`=@target_table
    ) AS `A`
) AS `B` ;     LIKE THIS ?

Comment: which part of the query should i place the CREATE TABLE gl_data as? Everywhere its giving error

Answer (score 0):

Add `AND COLUMN_NAME != 'acct'` to the `WHERE` condition in the query to exclude that column from the `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Concatenate `CREATE TABLE new_table_name` to the beginning of the query to make it create a new table with this result.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', QUOTE(new_table_name), ' AS ',
            GROUP_CONCAT(qry SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '))
    INTO @sql
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONCAT('SELECT `acct`,', QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME), ' AS `Business_Unit`,`', COLUMN_NAME, '` AS `value` FROM `', @target_table, '` WHERE ', @target_where) qry
    FROM (
        SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
        FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`=@target_schema 
            AND `TABLE_NAME`=@target_table
            AND `COLUMN_NAME` != 'acct'
    ) AS `A`
) AS `B` ;
```